# Why is this legal in Java? Queue<String> waitingQueue = new LinkedList<>();

Tags: java, syntax

In one of the tutorials on queues I saw following:

```
Queue<String> waitingQueue = new LinkedList<>();
```

Why is this statement valid in Java?

I have seen [What does it mean to "program to an interface"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface) but that does not explain the basic question of why above statement is valid. If Queue is an interface, how can I typecast an object to it? I can only implement Queue interface in a class to provide behavior I need.

What am I missing?

Comment: "I can only implement Queue interface in a class to provide behavior I need." But `LinkedList` already implements `Queue`. You're just saying "I want my variable to be able to contain a reference to an object of any class that implements `Queue`" - and then assigning it a value which is a reference to a `LinkedList`, because that implements `Queue`.

Comment: LinkedList is a class that implements the Queue interface. Why do you feel the above shouldn't be valid?

Comment: The basic skill to acquire here is to always look up the class you are not familiar with in the Java API documentation. In this case, look up [`LinkedList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## What is an interface

An interface is basically a contract saying "these are the methods that any class implementing this interface must implement".

Declaring a variable or field with an interface-type basically says "I don't care what the **specific** class is that gets assigned here, as longs as it follows the contract."

[`LinkedList`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/LinkedList.html) follows the contract set out by [`Queue`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Queue.html) by implementing all the required methods.

Therefor we can assign a reference to an object of type `LinkedList` to a variable of type `Queue`.

## "There can be no instance of an interface"

Developers often learn that "you can't instantiate an interface", which is correct but slightly misleading.

You **can** have an object that is *an instance of* an interface type by having an instance of a concrete class that implements that interface.

So while you can't execute `new Queue<String>()` (since you can't instantiate an interface) the expression `new LinkedList<String>()` actually returns a `Queue<String>` (because a `LinkedList<String>` *is-a* `Queue<String>`, in a similar way that it *is-a* `Object`).

Comment: Aha! So the benefit is to provide access to only those methods that are relevant for Queue!

Comment: @SuhasPatil-SWTestArchitect: the benefits are numerous, but your question didn't ask about those, only how it's possible. The question you linked to does a better job about what the advantages/disadvantages are.